# Dynamic Importing in Python (Dotted statments)

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
def get_module(mod_path):
    mod_list = mod_path.split('.')
    mod = __import__(mod_list.pop(0))

    while mod_list:
        mod = getattr(mod, mod_list.pop(0))

    return mod
```

When I do `get_module('qmbpmn.common.db_parsers')` I get the error message:
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'db_parsers'`.

However: `import qmbpmn.common.db_parsers` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `__import__` to import submodules, you must pass the parent package as the `fromlist` argument:

```
>>> __import__("os.path")
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/os.pyc'>
>>> __import__("os.path", fromlist=["os"])
<module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.pyc'>
```

Answer (score 1):

`__import__` works with the dotted module path, so this should work

```
def get_module(mod_path):
    return __import__(mod_path)
```

or more simply

```
get_module = __import__
```

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the problem

importing a package does not automatically import all the submodules into it's namespace. For example

```
import qmbpmn
```

does not mean that

```
qmbpmn.common.db_parsers
```

will automatically resolve